# Wireless not working when driver selected

Tags: wireless, drivers

I have a older laptop but I love Linux, I downloaded and installed the newest release last month of Ubuntu. I was running it duel-boot style. I can not get the Linux side to pick up the wireless signals. When I try to get the proprietary driver to install it starts and never finishes. I have let my laptop sit for hours and nothing. I deleted Ubuntu and figured I would ask in here first if there is an easier way to get Ubuntu up and running for dummies. I want Linux to function at its peak as I am in a lot of computer classes that makes it easier to have access to both operation systems. Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine had the same problem, try this:

open the **additional drivers** application, does it show the driver?

If so, uninstall it and leave it like that, don't try to reinstall it, just wait and try to connect the laptop via wifi

Sounds strange but my friend's laptop started working after this, give it a shot

Comment: I am in class right now and my install CD is at home but once I reinstall it at home I will give it a shot for sure. I will post how it goes, its gonna be an all nighter for me. Computer forensics is a pretty tough cookie to crack.